# Place Each 2 elements of unordered list on a single line

Tags: html, css, web

I have this unordered list and on phones with small screen width I want to place each 2 items on a single line, how can I implement that? thanks in advance.

```html
<a href="mailto:shouman882@gmail.com" class="footer_link">
shouman882@gmail.com
</a>

<ul class="social_list">

<li class="social_list_item"> <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://www.facebook.com/samtshouman">
 <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
 </a>
  </li>

<li class="social_list_item"> <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://github.com/SamShouman">
<i class="fab fa-github">
</i> 
</a> </li>



<li class="social_list_item"> <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://instagram.com/sam_shmn98?igshid=1k437cycqmauk">
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> 
</a> 
</li>

<li class="social_list_item"> <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=96103943517&source=&data=&app_absent=">
<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a> 
</li>



</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, it will wrap last 2 items when screen size decreases.

```css
.social_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first,
.second {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first li,
.second li {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:shouman882@gmail.com" class="footer_link">
shouman882@gmail.com
</a>

<ul class="social_list">

  <div class="first">


    <li class="social_list_item">
      <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://www.facebook.com/samtshouman">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>Facebook
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="social_list_item">
      <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://github.com/SamShouman">
        <i class="fab fa-github">GitHub
</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="second">

    <li class="social_list_item">
      <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://instagram.com/sam_shmn98?igshid=1k437cycqmauk">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="social_list_item">
      <a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=96103943517&source=&data=&app_absent=">
        <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>Whatsapp
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>


</ul>
```

Comment: it placed them next to each other

Comment: Ok, then the understanding is not correct, can you look into the result and tell me how should `row1,row2, row3 and row4` should look like?

Comment: the white space was fixed i was trying something and I forgot to delete it. So what I want is that the first and second item should on line1 and the third and fourth item should be on another line. Like this : Facebook GitHub on row1 and Instagram Whatsapp on row2

Comment: Ok, something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/m8q3v1x2/43/

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add     **width: 50%; float: left;** to the .social_list_item class with suitable media queries. The sample for a small width screen.

Refer this : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```css
/* You need to add suitable media queries for mobile devices. */
@media screen and  (max-width: 480px) {
    li.social_list_item {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:shouman882@gmail.com" class="footer_link">
    shouman882@gmail.com
</a>

<ul class="social_list">

    <li class="social_list_item"><a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://www.facebook.com/samtshouman">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="social_list_item"><a class="social_list_item_link" href="https://github.com/SamShouman">
        <i class="fab fa-github">
        </i>
    </a></li>


    <li class="social_list_item"><a class="social_list_item_link"
                                    href="https://instagram.com/sam_shmn98?igshid=1k437cycqmauk">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="social_list_item"><a class="social_list_item_link"
                                    href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=96103943517&source=&data=&app_absent=">
        <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your code did not work, it created extra white spaces and the elements are below each other

Comment: You need to add a suitable media query, try without using as     li.social_list_item {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }